# Why does jQuery immediately execute functions passed to .click()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am confused by the following code:

Code #1

```
$("#btn1").click(alert("hello"));
```

Code #2

```
$("#btn1").click(function() {
    alert("Btn 1 Clicked");
});
```

With Code #1, `alert` function is run without clicking the button. Why is the `alert` function called without the `click` event being fired? I thought a `click` function would only run when the user clicked on the button, then the `alert` function would be run after. Please correct me.

Could someone explain to me why these code samples behave differently?

Comment: but `alert("hello")` calls the alert function then passes the value returned by it as the click handler method

Comment: ok i guess you are a newbie to JS world. You need to read or try few exercise from any tutorials available on the net and try acquire basic understanding.

Comment: Okay, this is a newbie question, but why so many downvotes for this? @Nirus has a constructive comment, others should Close this topic instead of downvote.

Comment: for Downvoter i request you to point the OP in right direction as he is a newbie rather than downvoting and discouraging him from further exploring JS world.

Comment: The result at this moment is `+2|-6` :(

Comment: .click expects a function-reference or an closure, not a function!

Comment: @leguano not true. If the function returns a function then the code would be entirely valid. That's obviously not the case here, but to say providing a function is wrong is incorrect.

Comment: @Nirus I have downvoted for the very specific reason: the question shows no research effort. That's it. No matter if OP was new to the language or not.

Comment: Arun, why alert("hello") is called when event `click` not happen. Must I see `click` function in jQuery first?

Comment: @all yes, I am a newbie to JS. I know my question is downvoted when I ask. I searched alreay, but it maybe relate to callback function, what I have no idea about it. I ask because I hope someone explain the JS engine treats each code. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Example 1

```
$("#btn1").click(alert("hello"));
```

This evaluates the function `alert()` immediately, then passes the result to the click function. As the return value of alert is `undefined`, the jQuery code does nothing (as jQuery simply checks the first parameter type to determine what to do).

This test shows it does not fire an event: https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/qvut0jom/1/

Unless you provide a function *reference*, any function calls are evaluated immediately and the returned value is effectively substituted for the function call.

e.g with `a(b(c()))`, `c()` is called first then `b()` is called using the return value from `c()`. `a()` is then called using the return value of `b()`.

In your example, `alert()` is evaluated immediately (causing it to pop-up). It returns a value of `undefined` when you close it. That `undefined` value is then passed to `.click()`. That is the same as calling `.click(undefined)`, which in jQuery does nothing.

This handy reference shows the order that different operations are processed in Javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Note: A reference to a function is not evaluated until it is called (later).

### Example 2

```
$("#btn1").click(function() {
    alert("Btn 1 Clicked");
});
```

This passes a reference to an anonymous function, which is called-back when a click event occurs. This function call to `click` is simple registering a reference to the function, to be called at a later date.

You can also pass a non-anonymous function, like `alert`, by reference and it will be called-back later:

```
$("#btn1").click(alert);
```

This will call alert, as you intended in example 1, but obviously there are no way to pass parameters in this format.

Comment: Not quite correct. `.click(undefined)` wont trigger click event. I guess jquery checks for `arguments.length` to tell between triggers and binds.
https://jsfiddle.net/qvut0jom/

Comment: @YuryTarabanko: Corrected. Hardly worth a downvote though. The comment would have sufficed to get it fixed. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, TrueBlueAussie. I am digesting it with my poor JS knowledge. Maybe I ask more to clear the question, I will accept when I understand :) Thanks again

Comment: And another anonymous down-vote... Wannabe geniuses hiding behind anonymity... Learn to speak up or don't down-vote I say :)

Comment: "`a(b())`, `b()` is called first then `a()` is called using the return value of `b()`" Sorry, I still confuse this sentence. In my example #1, `click` is called or not, I thought it is not called yet, mapping to your sentence `a()` is not called yet. I am wrong?

Comment: Functions are evaluated from the innermost first. the `click` function *is* actually called in example 1, but it does nothing as it is passed a value of undefined (the return value from calling `alert`). Updated that part of answer to try and clarify.

Comment: @VuLeAnh: This may help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: I understand why with code#1, the popup does not appear when I click. But, I don't know why `click` is called when loading page, although I don't click on button yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100655/discussion-between-trueblueaussie-and-vu-le-anh).

Comment: Please clarify that. What do you mean "click is called when loading page"? A reference to an anonymous function is *registered* on page load using `.click(eventhandler)`. The problem is they use `.click` for two things.

Comment: could I chat with you?

Answer (score 2):

The first is a trigger and the second is a listener. To avoid this ambiguous behaviour, use `on()` and `trigger()` and you don't have never more a mistake:

### Listener:

```
 $('#btn1').on('click', function() {
        // do something when user clicks on btn1
 });
```

That's the same as

```
 $('#btn1').click(function() {
        // do something when user clicks on btn1
 });
```

### Trigger:

```
 $('#btn1').trigger('click'); // makes a click in btn1 without user intervention
```

That's the same as

```
 $('#btn1').click();
```

Comment: This isn't quite correct. Neither of the examples the OP has are equivalent to `trigger()`. The `alert()` is fired in the first example because it is called immediately and its return value is set as the handler for the click event. See the source for [click()](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.fn.click)

Comment: Marcos, thanks for your answer. I just want to understand how JS engine treat the code #1

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you're right, sorry, but in my answer all is correct. The truth is that the second example is not exactly as OP have got. But as an explanation, is a good explanation. Or not?

Comment: Actually the first example made the same incorrect assumption I did initially. It does **not** fire a click event if `undefined` is passed: https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/qvut0jom/1/

Comment: While the statements in your answer are absolutely correct, the OP's question is why the `alert('hello')` gets executed immediately, instead of waiting for the click even to be fired. So the answer is 'correct', but missed the question.

Comment: Yes @TedA. it's because I said to Rory McCrossan he is true, but my answer is not bad. Sorry for an answer that doesn't answer perfectly the question, my bad :(

Comment: Hey, I got a down-vote too and mine was accepted as correct. This site is not driven by common-sense. We just have to live with it :)

Comment: Yeah, I call that people "Trolls" (and many people thinks the same). I have 3 upvotes on this answer otherwise